# Unknown characters on TYPO3 tx_news list view (in Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, typo3, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

I noticed strange behaviour on TYPO3 tx_news list view. Sometimes on the bottom of the page appears unknown characters. I don't know how and why and it's only on one (list view) page and in chrome browser. Here is the screen shot of that:

[image]

I have noticed that I can call out that behaviour when I change some tx_news configuration in Extension Manager eg. "List actions shown in Flexforms"

Any suggestion what is wrong?

[EDIT:] After turn off OpCache - problem doesn't occur. Could it be related?

Comment: Yes, this could be related.

Answer (score 0):

You best bet is to install XDebug and call your page with ?XDEBUG_TRACE=1
You can then search for the offending pattern in your trace file and find the very first place where this offending pattern occurs (if it's not random of course). This gives you the very best chance to figure out why it appeared at all.